# The number of members in the conceptual type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am using VS 2010 with Entity Framework. I decide to create some relationships on a table. I started receiving the following message. I have been trying to find the answer and have tried some of the suggestions, but no luck. I can see that the MSMModel and MSM_Models do not match, I just do not understand which setting is not working correctly.

Can I manually sync the two tables? Do I need to bite the bullet and upgrade to VS 2012? Get rid of all of my relationships?

Error Message:

> The number of members in the conceptual type 'MSMModel.ShopPart' does not match with the number of members on the object side type 'MSM_Models.ShopPart'. Make sure the number of members are the same.

Comment: Did you regenerate your classes from your model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have tried that. I have deleted the classes in the .edmx and updated again. I have tried clearing the temp folder.

Today, I thought I would go a different direction. I deleted the relationships in the database and create them in the designer. It actually did not help. And thinking about it now, I kinda of understand why it would not. The error is telling me what is wrong. The navigation properties that are added are not being added to my model. I really think I have a settting off and I have to find it. I will have to dig deeper into Stackoverflow. Thanks.